# Blacklist DNS server?

Tags: networking, dns, arch-linux, manjaro

Is there any way to blacklist a DNS server in Manjaro?

At work, the router and VPN(s) hand out a public DNS as primary which simply does not work (likely due to some networking configuration issue here).

Mac users are okay because their OS seems to "realize this DNS does not work" and skips it for future lookups. Meanwhile, host lookups are taking 5-10 seconds for me. This puts a real hamper on productivity.

I'd like to configure Manjaro to use a similar auto-blacklist for DNS servers, if possible. I don't want to edit the DNS servers manually. In the meantime until the problem is resolved in the router / VPNs, is there anything I can do?

Comment: Your title is “Blacklist DNS server?” then you say “I'd like to configure Manjaro to use a similar auto-blacklist for DNS servers…” and my question is: Why are you assuming this is “blacklist” behavior? I have been using macOS for years and have never heard of DNS blacklisting happening.

Comment: @JakeGould -- I have colleagues using Macs. Their DNS config (e.g. `/etc/resolv.conf`) matches mine. They exhibit none of the issues I do with this single (primary) DNS server. So, I have assumed that Mac OS knows "this primary DNS sucks" and therefore skips it. But on Manjaro, every DNS lookup waits for the primary to timeout before moving to the next (5-10 seconds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `man resolv.conf`, you will notice that you can set a timeout options.

To quote the manual:

```
options
    [...]
    timeout:n
         Sets  the amount of time the resolver will wait for a response from a remote name server before
         retrying the query via a different name server. This may not be the total time taken by any re‐
         solver  API  call  and  there  is no guarantee that a single resolver API call maps to a single
         timeout.  Measured in seconds, the default is RES_TIMEOUT (currently 5, see  <resolv.h>).   The
         value for this option is silently capped to 30.
    [...]
```

So I'll suggest the following (as example):

```
search example.org
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.0.0.1
options timeout:3  # This is the line you need to add/edit for your need
```